# When s3cmd checks a bucket with thousands of files to sync it, does this count as one list request or thousands?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to figure out pricing here so I don't get overcharged. I daily run a backup script where s3cmd checks a folder with over one hundred thousand files to see if any have changed (which by the way, it takes close to an hour to do so), this is of course checking on the bucket and I am guessing this would be considered a list request, even if nothing is transferred. Very important question is, does this count as one list request or one hundred thousand list requests?

Been trying to find an answer for this, but it isn't very clear on their site:

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Note: LIST requests are limited to 1,000 objects, so it's going to be at least 100 requests, not one.

Comment: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/476 seems to indicate a request per file is possible.  "Yes, for all 'sync' commands, we are retrieving the metadata for each object." "We shouldn't be calling object_info() on all objects during a sync in the 1.5.2 release." seems to indicate it *may* be less hefty if you're on 1.5.2+, but I'd want to benchmark it to know for sure.